# MPI-based Implementations of FFT

Tags: parallel-computing, petsc, fourier-analysis, fftw

In a numerical computation, I am required to take a multi-dimensional FFT on a distributed-memory cluster. The data is currently distributed using a distributed array in PETSc (DMDA).

I initial looked at the distributed version of FFTW. However, the layout of my data does not conform to the layout used by FFTW. Therefore, I would need to scatter my data to the layout required by FFTW which would not be ideal. See [link](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-3.2/src/mat/examples/tests/ex158.c.html) for an example using PETSc.

Note, the FFT is not the dominant bottleneck in my computation. I just want to minimize the communication overhead required for the FFT. Does anyone have any suggestions for what I should be using? Is FFTW the optimal approach even when my data does not conform to FFTW layout?

Comment: I could construct a multi-dimensional transform using multiple 1d FFTW transforms. I don't know if this is the most efficient way of doing this though.

Comment: I came across an FFT developed at the Sandia National Laboratories which might have some potential. http://www.sandia.gov/~sjplimp/docs/fft/README.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Michael Pippig at the University of Chemnitz (Germany) has implemented an MPI-parallelized FFT that uses FFTW in the background. This might help you: http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~mpip/software.php?lang=en

It is using the algorithm proposed by Plimpton from Sandia National Labs as suggested by Eldila's comment.